# 2008 DC DHCP Inquiry

Tags: dhcp, domain-controller

We have a few servers mainly for SVN, File and nightly builds. We only use the DC for ALC.

Currently, I'm using the Sonicwall's Built in DHCP to issue IP's to developers. Of course if the firewall locks or gets corrupted then network access is lost.

I have our primary DC configured with DHCP and all my address pools allocated, but I've disabled them for the moment because if I'm not mistaken (which I probably am) when a request to the DC's DHCP server is made, the user must first be authenticated before it returns a valid list of available address to pull from. Since the developers are logging in to local profiles and not through AD, then the request would be denied - correct?

Am I right here? I don't want to get stuck in a mess of no network access if I'm wrong and I switch over to the WS2008 DHCP and turn the sonicwall's off.

Comment: No. You do not have to authenticate to get an ip address form a Windows DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to authenticate to get an IP from DHCP. It has to be domain-joined for DNS registration, but that's different. We use DHCP at our company on various devices just fine.